# Why do I appear to get incorrect rolling std from Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get rolling std from a float array.

I have written rolling_std2() to do this via pandas:

```
data = my_large_array

def rolling_std2(observations, n):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Obs'] = observations
    df['Std'] = df.Obs.rolling(n).std()
    return df['Std'].values

shortSTD = rolling_std2(data , 100)
longSTD = rolling_std2(data , 5000)

                                data   shortSTD    longSTD
utcDT 
<missing large number of rows>                                                
2020-09-07 23:55:00+00:00 0.00001282 0.00000978 0.00496809
2020-09-07 23:56:00+00:00 0.00000656 0.00000979 0.00496809
2020-09-07 23:57:00+00:00 0.00000537 0.00000980 0.00496809
2020-09-07 23:58:00+00:00 0.00000194 0.00000980 0.00496809
2020-09-07 23:59:00+00:00 0.00000252 0.00000980 0.00496809
2020-09-08 00:01:00+00:00 0.00000319 0.00000978 0.00496809
2020-09-08 00:02:00+00:00 0.00001175 0.00000981 0.00496809
2020-09-08 00:03:00+00:00 0.00004597 0.00001075 0.00496809
2020-09-08 00:04:00+00:00 0.00004204 0.00001146 0.00496809
2020-09-08 00:05:00+00:00 0.00002646 0.00001171 0.00496809
```

longSTD does not appear to be correct, its value should be changing.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Cant really help much unless we see how the data looks like

Comment: Interesting! can you share data so we may test this? One immediate quetion though: What is the variance of your data (observations)?

Comment: data has 3 million rows - not sure how to share

Comment: How about the variance? If the data you have has very little variance (at least piecewise), you will not expect large changes i std.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your function. As I mentioned in the comment section, a rolling `std` with a window of that size will probably cause what you percieve as not normal IF there is very variance in your data. Here is an example that illustrates this. I created 2 array with random values within two different intervals, `[0.001, 0.01]` and the other `[0.001, 0.1]`, put them i a dataframe, applied

```
array1  = np.random.uniform(low=0.001, high=0.01, size=(1000000,))
array2  = np.random.uniform(low=0.001, high=0.1, size=(1000000,))
DF      = pd.DataFrame(array1,array2).reset_index()
DF2     = DF.rename(columns={'index': "A",0: "B"})


def rolling_std2(observations, n):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Obs'] = observations
    df['Std'] = df.Obs.rolling(n).std()
    return df['Std'].values


shortSTDA  = rolling_std2(DF2['A'] , 100)
longSTDA   = rolling_std2(DF2['A'] , 5000)
shortSTDB  = rolling_std2(DF2['B'] , 100)
longSTDB   = rolling_std2(DF2['B'] , 5000)
FULL1      = pd.DataFrame(shortSTDA,shortSTDB)
FULL2      = pd.DataFrame(longSTDA,longSTDB).reset_index()
FULL2 = FULL2.rename(columns={'index': "longSTDA",0: "longSTDB"})
print(FULL2.tail(100))
```

and got this dataframe

```
        longSTDA  longSTDB
999900  0.002614  0.028806
999901  0.002615  0.028806
999902  0.002615  0.028804
999903  0.002615  0.028804
999904  0.002615  0.028804
...          ...       ...
999995  0.002612  0.028762
999996  0.002612  0.028761
999997  0.002612  0.028756
999998  0.002612  0.028755
999999  0.002611  0.028758
```

As you see, the `longSTD` for the array with a narrow interval shows very little variance. Check the variance in your data.

Comment: But you are getting SOME changes. I am getting none in the example I have shown you

Comment: Is there a Stackoverflow way to send you 10K rows?

Comment: So, you mean the entire ```df[longSTB]``` is equal to ```0.00496809```??

Comment: Yes - it appears to remain constant

Comment: It's complicated to share data like this. You could (unless your data is sensitive) send it in an email (sergedegossondevarennes@gmail.com). A positive point though is that your function actually does what it should, as my example illustrates.